# Stripping down SVG Code

Tags: css, html, svg

I have created SVG code from coreldraw and want to place it inline in my HTML5 document and have a couple of queries.

1. How universal is SVG now-a-days?  Any suggestions on backwards compatibility?
2. I have taken out the style data from the svg and put that into my css, I guess that's not a problem - or is it?  I also added a hover rule...

`.Borderline {stroke:#0099FF;stroke-width:7.45541;stroke-linejoin:round}
    .BorderFill1 {fill:#71C6FF}
    .BorderFill2 {fill:#CBEAFF}
    .BorderFill1:hover {fill: green; }`

1. Can I remove any of the following data that is not needed. (but I want it to work and look the same)

`<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="myimgleft" xml:space="preserve" width="100px" height="105px" version="1.1" style="shape-rendering:geometricPrecision; text-rendering:geometricPrecision; image-rendering:optimizeQuality; fill-rule:evenodd; clip-rule:evenodd" viewBox="0 0 92 97" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <g id="Layer_x0020_1">
    <metadata id="CorelCorpID_0Corel-Layer"/>
    <path class="BorderFill1 Borderline" d="M55 51c10,0 18,0 24,0 4,-5 9,-10 9,-15 0,-6 0,-22 0,-32l-16 14c-5,-4 -8,-6 -17,-14l0 47z"/>
    <path class="BorderFill2 Borderline" d="M79 51c-5,-1 -41,0 -47,0l0 -14c-8,8 -25,25 -28,28l28 28 0 -13c7,0 11,1 17,-2 6,-2 23,-21 30,-27z"/>
    </g>
    </svg>`

1. Any other hints / tips that might be useful are very welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 MDN keeps an accurate list of compatibility per-element. Here's the list for SVG: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/svg

`Feature    Chrome  Firefox (Gecko)     IE  Opera   Safari
Basic support   1.0     1.5 (1.8)      9.0  8.0     3.0.4`

2 Keep the style in your SVG - it'll make it easier to swap out for other SVG images later. You want to be able to quickly update your svg. This one is more a matter of preference.

3 I wouldn't get in the habit of tweaking vector-art exported from CorelDraw by hand. You may think to run it through a minifier, but hand-tuning is almost certainly more work than it's worth.

Here's the first minifier Google gives me:
http://petercollingridge.appspot.com/svg-optimiser
For cases where you're not inlining, you can give .svgz (compressed svg) a shot, which will make it significantly smaller: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/24797/when-should-i-use-svg-or-svgz-for-my-web-graphics

4 Hmm, other tips - well good on you for using vector art on your site. Too many web devs/designers take the shortcut of doing everything in raster. While that gets you a nice looking image for a demo, in the long run it's really hurting your site. With ubiquitous tablets + phones, pinch + zoom is everywhere and your images need to scale nicely.

Personally, I've never loved the idea of inlining svg - I've always preferred saving as .svg and src-ing it like an image. I see why you are inlining it, though, as you're using some hovers.

Comment: Thanks for that, really useful stuff...  All my previous work was with svg files, but thought it would be nice to style it on hover, where it seems to REQUIRE you to have it inline (as far as I can tell).  I'm quite a novice at all of this but do like to tinker...